# How to put double quote in oracle output records

Tags: oracle

This is a oracle output records with pipe delimiter

```
04/22/2015|695|1074795|CRUSE|AXDE|01/29/1963|88359|||||
```

I want to change like this

```
"04/22/2015"|"695"|"1074795"|"CRUSE"|"AXDE"|"01/29/1963"|"88359"|||||
```

What is the query in Perl?

Comment: Can't you change the Oracle procedure to make it output the results encased with double-quotes?

Answer (score 0):

> I want to change like this
>
> "04/22/2015"|"695"|"1074795"|"CRUSE"|"AXDE"|"01/29/1963"|"88359"|||||

I won't say this is an elegant way to do it, since it is always better to fix the source itself. In your case, whatever is generating the output, you could simply **concatenate** the **double-quotation marks** to the **column names**.

Anyway, you could do it in SQL using **REPLACE** and **RTRIM**:

```
SQL> WITH DATA AS(
  2  SELECT '04/22/2015|695|1074795|CRUSE|AXDE|01/29/1963|88359|||||' str FROM dual
  3  )
  4  SELECT '"'||rtrim(REPLACE(REPLACE(str, '|', '"|"'), '""',''),'"') str FROM DATA;

STR
---------------------------------------------------------------------
"04/22/2015"|"695"|"1074795"|"CRUSE"|"AXDE"|"01/29/1963"|"88359"|||||

SQL>
```

Comment: ** How to use this query in perl**
How to this part of query in perl 
 '"'||rtrim(REPLACE(REPLACE(str, '|', '"|"'), '""',''),'"')

Comment: If this is an output from Oracle, then why can't you do the same in Oracle itself? How is perl related here? Moreover, your question has only `oracle` tag. So, this answer should suffice.

Answer (score 0):

check this

```
    select '"04/22/2015"|"695"|"1074795"|"CRUSE"|"AXDE"|"01/29/1963"|"88359"|||||' as str from dual 

STR                                                                   
--------------------------------------------------------------------- 
"04/22/2015"|"695"|"1074795"|"CRUSE"|"AXDE"|"01/29/1963"|"88359"|||||
```